# How do i check that ros-indigo-image-pipeline package is available for kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working with Jackal and all their codes and packages imply to use indigo but i currently have kinetic. Here is a link to the website i am using as reference.
http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/jackal/network.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292064/if-i-currently-have-kinetic-instead-of-indigo,-and-i-have-to-install-a-package-that-was-design-for-indigo,-(ros-indigo-image-pipeline)-how-do-i-check-that-i-can-replace-indigo-with-kinetic-or-if-it-is-even-available-for-kinetic?/) by [xiswitchx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30886/xiswitchx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First a quick answer: I've used Kinetic with a Jackal running Indigo many times and have run into very few issues. `image_pipeline` is certainly released on Kinetic and can be installed using `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-pipeline`. You likely already have this package installed.

A good question is how to check what packages are released for a particular distro (allowing installation from `apt-get`)? You could:

1. Check using `apt-cache` on your machine (e.g. `apt-cache search image-pipeline`)
2. Check the wiki. Note every package page has status indicators at the top highlighting if a package has been released or not. Notice the green "Released button" on the [image_pipeline](http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline) page when you select Kinetic?
3. There are also several tools online for checking build status. These are likely less useful if you are not a package maintainer, but if you are trying to track down an issue it's good to know these exist. http://build.ros.org/ and http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html could both be useful.

If a particular package you need to use isn't released on your target ROS distro, you can always try building from source by obtaining a copy of the source (typically a `git clone` will do this), and putting it into catkin workspace and trying to build. The multitude of issues that can arise when building from source is a whole other can of worms.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xiswitchx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30886/xiswitchx/) on 2018-05-23**:
Thank you, this was very helpful. I am just getting started with ROS and Jackal seems like a good project to start and get a hang of things. Hopefully the few issues you ran into with Kinetic and Indigo are not that bad and I can figure it out.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-05-24**:
IIRC, the only issue I've run into is with the message definition of `visualization_msgs/Marker` changing between Indigo and Kinetic (as described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/261071/rviz-client-md5sum-error/) ). Note that most Jackal packages have been released on Kinetic, so it could...

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-05-24**:
... be possible to update Jackal to 16.04+Kinetic. I haven't tried this, but if you do run into issues it might be worth reaching out to Clearpath.